# Is there a way to enforce email verification before registering a user using FirebaseUI for flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm following along this codelab: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-auth-in-flutter-apps#0

Here's the auth_gate from the lab:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'
    hide EmailAuthProvider, PhoneAuthProvider;
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_ui_oauth_google/firebase_ui_oauth_google.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'home.dart';

class AuthGate extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthGate({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return SignInScreen(
            providers: [
              EmailAuthProvider(),
              PhoneAuthProvider(),
              GoogleProvider(
                  clientId:
                      YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
            ],
            headerBuilder: (context, constraints, shrinkOffset) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/flutterfire_300x.png'),
                ),
              );
            },
            subtitleBuilder: (context, action) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                child: action == AuthAction.signIn
                    ? const Text('Welcome to FlutterFire, please sign in!')
                    : const Text('Welcome to Flutterfire, please sign up!'),
              );
            },
            footerBuilder: (context, action) {
              return const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text(
                  'By signing in, you agree to our terms and conditions.',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              );
            },
            sideBuilder: (context, shrinkOffset) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/flutterfire_300x.png'),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }

        return const HomeScreen();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

As it stands right now, you can register with any email address you want (like superman@gmail.com) and it will successfully add the user to Firebase. I would like to find a way to require the email to be verified first, before the user is added to Firebase and someone can sign in with it. I'm very stuck, so any help would be appreciated!

I tried pushing an actions parameter to the SignInScreen like so:

```
  actions: [
    AuthStateChangeAction<SignedIn>((context, state) {
      if (!state.user!.emailVerified) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/verify-email');
      } else {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/profile');
      }
    }),
```

but this didn't really have an effect.To be clear, I'm looking for a way to use the out of the box SigninScreen provided by FirebaseUI for flutter, and add something to enforce email verification on registration to it.

Comment: To be able to send a verification email, the user must be first signed into Firebase. But you can of course prevent them from using the rest of your app until their email address has been verified. If that's not the flow you want, consider using [email link authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/email-link-auth) as that combines signing in with verifying the email address.